# DMGBuild: how to make folder invisible on dmg

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, dmg

I use the dmgbuild tool to create nice looking Disk Images on MacOS (pip install dmgbuild).
This works very well for me.

But does someone know how to make a folder, who is added on the dmg, **invisible**?
I don't think it is supported by the current dmgbuild code, is it?

Comment: I don't know anything about dmgbuild, but have you tried to create a folder with its name starting with a dot (.myInvisibleFolder)? Those are "invisible" by default in Linux or Mac.

Comment: If you can find that folders icon, you could replace it with one you like.

Comment: Have you looked at the dmgbuild usage page https://dmgbuild.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html. It has inputs in the settings file for the icon used.

Comment: @jmh In the documentation they talk only about the volume icon and the badge icon. Not about the icons of the files/folders you include.

Comment: @Yoric This could be a possible solution but this means that I need to make the folder invisible somewhere before building the dmg itself. Because I then need to refer to this .invisiblefolder in the settings.py file of the python dmgbuild tool. [SettingsFile](https://dmgbuild.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#files).  I just hoped it could be done easier, completely via the settings.py file.